# Why do I get an error in Python when I try to read several strings with spaces in between from stdin?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I don't know why my online ide throws an error when I execute this code:

```
n = int(input())

lst = []

for i in range(n):
    lst.append(input())

print(lst)
```

When I give these as input:

```
5
first string
second string
third string
almost done
done now
```

I get this error:

```
$python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 6, in <module>
    lst.append(input())
  File "<string>", line 1
    first string
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Funny thing is, I run the same code with the same input on VS Code and face no errors, and even get the result:

```
['first string', 'second string', 'third string', 'almost done', 'done now']
```

What's happening? I'm confused...

Comment: Which IDE is this?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur The first one can be found here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/online_python_ide.php and the second one is VS Code. First one throws an error, second one works just fine

Comment: On the online IDE, check if the language is Python 3+ and not Python 2.7

Comment: @AbhinavMathur oh, it is python 2.7; is that the problem?

Comment: Yes; Python 2.7 needs `raw_input` for this.  You should not be using 2.7 any more; it was deprecated over a year ago.

Comment: @Prune Sure I don't use 2.7 at all, that's why I got confused, cause I've always worked with 3+ and this kinda stressed me out :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the online IDE uses Python 2.7, where you need to use `raw_input()` to handle the input correctly. You need something like this:

```py
n = int(input())

lst = []

for i in range(n):
    lst.append(raw_input().strip())

print(lst)
# prints ['first string', 'second string', 'third string', 'almost done', 'done now']
```

You can read more about the difference between `input` and `raw_input` [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-input-and-raw_input-functions-in-python/).

Comment: Oh, I did not know about this... I always only worked with python 3+... Thank you so much for your solution! I appreciate your help very much :)